# Whats the scope of a c function defined within objective-c class?

Tags: c, objective-c, function, scope

I was reading up about bypassing objective-c's messaging to gain performance (irrelevant to this specific question) when i found an interesting bit of code:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Fib : NSObject { }

- (long long) cFib: (NSUInteger) number;

@end

@implementation Fib

// c implementation of fib
long long cFibIMP(NSUInteger number)
{
  return (number < 3) ? 1 : cFib(number - 1) + cFib(number - 2);
}

// method wrapper for c implementation of fib
- (long long) cFib: (NSUInteger) number
{
  return cFibIMP(number);
}

@end
```

My question is; when using c function, within an objective-c object, what scope is the c function (cFibIMP in this particular case) placed in? Does the objective-c class encapsulate the c function removing change of name-clash or is the c function simply dumped into the global scope of the whole objective-c program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions are dumped in the "global" scope.

You can check this by adding a new class at the end of your sample code:

```
@interface Gib : NSObject {}
@end
@implementation Gib
- (void) t
{
    NSLog(@"%d", cFibIMP(10));
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The C function has global scope.

If you want to have something like "class" scope, your best bet is probably to use the `static` keyword, which limits the scope of the function to the source file in which it is contained.  For the sort of usage you're illustrating here, that's usually close enough.

Comment: so prepending static to the function declaration would restrict it's scope to the module then? Does this apply even though that static declaration is made internal to the @implementation as opposed to being made outside (i.e. at the beginning of the source code file?)